# Any "hover" hacks for mobile shop page on Squarespace to show secondary image?

Tags: css, mobile, squarespace

On my current shop page if you hover the mouse over the product the second image pops up which is useful to see the blanket unfolded. I'm curious if there's a way to have the second image show up either under the first image or next to the first image on the mobile site since hover isn't applicable to mobile. I've seen other shops where you can swipe the product image on the shop page in mobile to achieve the same action as hover. Is this possible with css?

thank you!

This is one solution another forum gave me

```
/* Mobile shop images */
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.ProductList-image {
    position: static !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 50% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.ProductList-innerImageWrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row !important;
}
}
```

but the second image doesn't show up and the first ones ends up all stretched.

URL: [https://caminito.co/shop]